# Apple Pay sheet Product description and specifications

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, applepay

This app is in the store from 2015 and never have problem with apple pay.
Recently i made an update and submit the app to the store but it was Rejected, this is the information reported in the review:

Your app uses Apple Pay as a purchasing mechanism but does not use Apple Pay branding and user interface elements appropriately as described in the Apple Pay Human Interface Guidelines.

Specifically, your Apple Pay sheet does not include the following:

- Product description and specifications
- payee name

This is the screenshot of my Apple Pay sheet

[image]

what does it mean "Product description and specifications"? do I have to add all the products purchased? I never see the products in apple pay sheet..
also i read this https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay/overview/checkout-and-payment/ and there isn't any reference to products

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The total line should include your payee name, as per the guidelines;

> **Provide a business name after the word PAY on the same line as the total.** Use the same business name people will see when they look for the charge on their bank or credit card statement. This provides reassurance that payment is going to the right place. For example: PAY [COMPANY_NAME].

You can see [more examples](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/) on Apple's site - Note how it says "PAY THE NORTH FACE" and "PAY DOORDASH".

The guidelines don't say anything about product description and specifications, but you should include lines for the subtotal and VAT if applicable.

I would fix this and resubmit.  If Apple still has a problem with product description, I would request more information from them.

Comment: added company name and resubmitted the app: passed validation.

Comment: How can we add the "Product description and specifications" in Apple pay dialog option?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentrequest/1619231-paymentsummaryitems

Answer (score 1):

You can add the payee name like this

```
paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Payee name", amount: 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest you should add your company or app name after the word "Pay" before the total, or to be accurate [doc](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/apple-pay#Customizing-the-payment-sheet) says *"Use the same business name people will see when they look for the charge on their bank or credit card statement."* but for me I used the app name, and that is enough

So for those who are using Flutter and [pay](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) package you can do this in the method `showPaymentSelector` in the payment item with the type total:

```
await paymentClient.showPaymentSelector(PayProvider.apple_pay, [
          PaymentItem(
              amount: cart.value!.subTotalWithoutTax.toStringAsFixed(2),
              status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
              type: PaymentItemType.item,
              label: LocalKeys.kSubtotal.tr),
         ...
          PaymentItem(
            amount: cart.value!.total.toStringAsFixed(2),
            status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
            type: PaymentItemType.total,
            label: "Company Name", //In here use your app or company name
          ),
        ]);
```

My app has been rejected for this reason and by these changes, my app got approved and released